# Does every plane curve have an implicit form?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, plane-curves, parametrization, implicit-function

One of our professors said every connected plane curve has an implicit form. That is, it can be written in this form:
$F(x,y)=0$
After some searching, I found this article:

Look at page 23:
[Conversion Methods between Parametric and Implicit Curves and Surfaces](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-20-winter/Handouts/a228715.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwibzKrtubzwAhXSGs0KHf2hD4gQFjALegQIKBAC&usg=AOvVaw3FVgBIvcK1P4Qe9SwexEfJ)

It has been said that every plane parametric curve has an implicit form.

How can it be proved?

Comment: What exactly is the definition of a *connected plane curve* in this context?  Usually a curve is *defined* as a (continuous) map from a non-empty interval into a topological space.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe maybe my professor wanted to emphasize 

Comment: For every closed subset $C$ of the plane, the function $F(X) = d(X, C) = \min\{d(X, Y) : Y \in C\}$ is a continuous function vanishing precisely on $C$. That may be what your professor had in mind? <> Often when people speak of "implicit form", however, the curve has some special form, e.g., is an algebraic curve, and "implicit" means the defining function $F$ may be chosen to be a rational function or some such. That's a more subtle issue....

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang No, he really meant implicit function. In the process of converting a second order PDE (which can be hyperbolic, parabolic, or elliptic) into the standard form, he mentioned that fact.